# DAX - Frequency of Selected Values as a calculated Column

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I have a simple table here:

[image]

I need to make a measure that counts records grouped by the Number column.

Ideally:

[image]

I also need this measure to by dynamic for whatever records are selected. So if a subset of the table is being used:
(Same example table, but with 2 less records)
[image]

Then the ideal output would be:
Now output for number '1' is 2 instead of 4.
[image]

Some of the code I tried:

```
    ,"CNT",COUNTROWS(ALLSELECTED([Table1]))
,"Summz",SUMMARIZE(ALLSELECTED(Table1),"CNT",COUNTROWS(Table1))
,"CALC",CALCULATE(COUNT(Table1[Rownum]),ALLEXCEPT(Table1,Table1[Number]))
,"CALCII",CALCULATE(
            SUMX(
                ADDCOLUMNS(
                    SUMMARIZE(Table1,Table1[Rownum])
                ,"Freq",DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[Number])
                ),
                [Freq])
                ,REMOVEFILTERS(Table1[Rownum])
            )
```

[image]

I feel like I'm close but not getting it. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Freq = CALCULATE( COUNT(Table1[Number]), ALLEXCEPT(Table1,Table1[Number]))
```

Comment: Almost. I need to explain the question further.
This measure needs to be dynamic for what is selected within a visual. So if a subset of the data is used, the frequency calculated will account for that. This code does satisfy the ideal output, but it is not dynamic. (Question edited)

Comment: Try this: Freq = CALCULATE( COUNT(Table1[Number]),  ALLSELECTED(Table1), VALUES(Table1[Number]))